# LED capable of either IR or visible light (not at the same time)

Tags: components, component-selection

I'm looking for a type of LED (or some other small light emitter) with two modes:

- IR light only
- Visible light, if it also emits IR light here it doesn't really matter

Could something like an "RGB LED" be used to change spectrum outside of the visible?

Background stuff:

I want to use these in a costume at a convention with a fun twist. When people use cameras (can receive IR light) they will see things not visible in the real world. I want to be able to switch it into the visible spectrum at various points though. And as it will be used in clothing I don't have much space for two LEDs(IR + normal).

Thanks for your time

Comment: Beware many cameras have built in IR filters.

Comment: @Axis While this is true, they're mostly intended to block low levels of ambient IR. Concentrated IR emitters, like LEDs, are quite visible to most cameras.

Comment: A fun way to test it is to point your cellphone camera at your TV remote when you press a button, you'll be able to see the IR signal sent

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Emitters with both infrared and visible light can be found by searching for "infrared dual emitter" or "infrared dual LED".

For instance, one such part available in my geography is the Osi Opto [DLED-660/940-CSL-3](http://www.osioptoelectronics.com/Libraries/Product-Data-Sheets/Dual-LED-Assemblies.sflb.ashx), a side-emitting LED with 660 nm red and 940 nm IR, independently controllable (common anode).

[image: DLED datasheet extract]

The bidirectional (CSL-2) type might be preferable for simplistic applications such as mentioned by OP, where inverting the voltage would switch between IR and visible emission, without both being needed simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

No LED can produce more than one color or wavelength. The color emitted by an LED is determined by the [band gap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_gap) of the semiconductor material the LED is made out of. In order to make different color LEDs, they must be made out of different materials with different band gaps. For example, a red LED might be made of gallium phosphide (GaP), while a green LED might be made of aluminum gallium indium phosphide (AlInGaP).

Devices sold as "two-color" or "RGB" LEDs are actually two or three LEDs mounted in a single package.

> Could something like an "RGB LED" be used to change spectrum outside of the visible?

Yes, a visible-wavelength LED and an IR LED could be packaged together like in an RGB LED.

Whether such a product is available on the market, I don't know.